# React Hook Form - formState is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am trying to use React-Hook-Forms in my react application and I am using version 7 of react-hook-form and I am getting an error which says that " **formState is not defined** " though it is imported and used properly.
This is the piece of code that I am using in my application which appears right according to the documentation provided here :- https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/formstate

```
const LoginForm = () => {
const { register, setError ,formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();
const {sendSignInLinkToEmail} = useAuth();

const onSubmit = async data => {
    // console.log(data);
    try{
        await sendSignInLinkToEmail(data.email);
    }catch (error) {
        setError("email", {
            type: "manual",
            message: error.message,
        });
    }
}

console.log(errors);
return(
    <GridItem>
      
        { errors.email && (
            <Alert status="error" variant="subtle" mt={6} mb={6}>
                <AlertIcon />
                {errors.email.message}
            </Alert>
        )}

        {formState.isSubmitSuccessful && (
            <Alert status="success" variant="subtle" mt={6} mb={6}>
            <AlertIcon />
            Check your email to complete login !!
        </Alert>
        )}
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <FormControl>
                <FormLabel htmlFor="email">Email</FormLabel>
                <Input name="email" placeholder="Email" {...register('email')}></Input>
                <Button mt={4} colorScheme="teal" isLoading={formState.isSubmitting} type="submit">Login</Button>
            </FormControl>
        </form>
    </GridItem>
)
}
```

But I am getting this error

```
Line 50:14:  'formState' is not defined  no-undef
Line 60:66:  'formState' is not defined  no-undef
```

and line 50 is

```
{formState.isSubmitSuccessful && (
        <Alert status="success" variant="subtle" mt={6} mb={6}>
        <AlertIcon />
        Check your email to complete login !!
    </Alert>
    )}
```

and line 60 is

```
<Button mt={4} colorScheme="teal" isLoading={formState.isSubmitting} type="submit">Login</Button>
```

Also **errors** here from useForm is not getting implemented properly , setError is not setting the "error" object with the error that occurs , What is going wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of your destructuring of formState to errors `{formState:{errors}}` will only return errors, you can take rest props of formState without erros like `{formState:{errors, ...formState}}` or something like that, or just simply use `formState.errors`

Comment: This worked , I used formState.errors and everything works just fine , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should also use `register` to apply validation properly.

read here:

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/

Comment: Thanks for this , I went through the documentation and found the right way , it seemed I was looking at a newer version documentation and was using a old version react-hook-form. Thanks !!